# How to add Home button using Card View Button in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-cardview, back-button, android-homebutton

This is my layout and i want to move to home page with a single click.

[[Added a Photo]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T30fM.png)eKv.png

My home button card view code is here

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_home"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_home"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: in your activity or fragment after initializing the views use an [OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/button#ClickListener) on the imageview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand what you mean by go to home page?

If u want to go HomeActivity/MainActivity,
Just set a listener on the imageButton with an intent to start your home activity

**Kotlin**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var imageButton : ImageButton
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.iv_home)

        imageButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

**Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton imageButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.iv_home);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Firstly, I mean in my app... eg., HomeScreen/subTask1/subTask2/subTask3 .... Now I want to add a button on subTask3 to go direct on HomeScreen of my App. I hope you got it.
Secondly, I want to add a button with image only (like my posted image). I tried with ImageButton but don't know why I can't place the im_btn perfectly in my relative layout, so I used card view.

Comment: Can u tell me that if your tasks are activities/fragments?
Also you could try to use ConstraintLayout as it is much easier to align views.

Comment: @M Ashhal Yeah you are right but I need to attached some text as well as icon also. and thank you for your answer and I fixed it.